# Can I achieve ordered processing with multiple consumers in Kafka?

Tags: message-queue, apache-kafka

In Kafka, I have a producer queuing up work of clients. Each piece of work has a client ID on it. Work of different clients can be processed out of order, but work of one client must be processed in order.

To do this, I intend to have (for example) 20 topics to achieve parallelism. The producer will queue up work of a client ID into `topic[client ID mod 20]`. I then intend to have many consumers each capable of processing work of any client but I still want the work processed in order. This means that the next price of work in the topic can't begin to be processed before the previous piece has completed. In case of consumer failure it's OK to process work twice, but it means that the offset of that topic can't progress to the next piece of work.

Note: the number of messages per second is rather small (10s-100s messages).

To sum up:

- 'At least once' processing of every message (=work)
- In order processing of work for one topic
- Multiple consumers for every topic to support consumer failure

Can this be done using Kafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with Kafka. But you shouldn't do it quite the way you've described. Kafka already supports semantic partitioning within a topic if you provide a key with each message. In this case you'd create a topic with 20 partitions, then make the key for each message the client ID. This guarantees all messages with the same key end up in the same partition, i.e. it will do the partitioning that you were going to do manually.

When consuming, use the high level consumer, which automatically balances partitions across available consumers. If you want to absolutely guarantee at least once processing, you should commit the offsets manually and make sure you have fully processed messages you have consumed before committing them. Beware that consumers joining or leaving the group will cause rebalancing of partitions across the instances, and you'll have to make sure you handle that correctly (e.g. if your processing is stateful, you'll have to make sure that state can be moved between consumers upon rebalancing).

Comment: Is there a sort of leader election between the consumers of a partition of a topic? So that if a consumer fails to process a range of offsets - a different consumer takes on the work? Thanks

Comment: If you use the high level consumer they coordinate to load balance partitions. At any given time, only one consumer instance in the group will be assigned each partition. Usually you will see the consumer instance leave the group entirely (i.e. the process dies), which will cause partitions to be rebalanced and a different consumer instance will pick up the slack.